# Trigger AngularJS $scope event on key press

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to trigger a `$scope function` on keypress. I like to know whats the most comfortable way to handle key press in a "form case". I created a dummy [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n2itgwda4HVyQEfztoJG?p=preview).

### Controller

```
// Code goes here
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

//main controller define
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', MainCtrl]);

/**
 * MainCtrl object wrapper
 */
function MainCtrl ($scope) {

  /**
   * Submit function
   */
  $scope.submit = function () {
    console.log('Submit was triggered');
  }
}
```

### View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Trigger on enter key" />
      <button ng-click="submit();">Trigger on click</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a `form` tag and using `ng-submit`

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Trigger on enter key" />
    <button>Trigger on click</button>
</form>
```